# Single Legend for a Table of Plots

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, legending

For this toy problem

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]

GraphicsGrid[
 Partition[
  Table[ListPlot[
    Table[{x, f[x]}, {f, {Sin, Cos}}, {x, 0, Pi, Pi/10.}], 
    PlotRange -> {{0, Pi}, {-1, 1}}, 
    PlotLegend -> {"Sine", "Cosine",}, LegendPosition -> {1.1, -0.4}, 
    PlotMarkers -> Automatic], {k, 1, 6, 1}], 3], Spacings -> 0, 
 ImageSize -> 700]
```

I was trying to make a single legend (precisely the legend you see here four times) for the entire `GraphicsGrid` rather than the same legend four times. How do I do so?

---

**Edit:** Same question but now with v9 code that doesn't require loading any package:

```
GraphicsGrid[
 Partition[
  Table[ListPlot[{Sqrt[Range[50]], Power[Range[50], (3)^-1]}, 
    PlotLegends -> 
     PointLegend[Automatic, {"one", "two"}, LegendFunction -> "Frame",
       LegendLabel -> "datasets"]], {k, 1, 6}], 3], ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

Comment: which version are you using? Version 9 has built-in plot legends which is better than the old package.

Comment: I am using v9...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can generate the legends separately with version 9's legends, but you'll have to manually input the colors (i.e. `Automatic` won't work):

```
With[{cols = {Red, Blue}},
    Column[{
        GraphicsGrid[
            Partition[
                Table[
                    ListPlot[{Sqrt[Range[50]], Power[Range[50], (3)^-1]}, PlotStyle -> cols], 
                    {k, 1, 6}
                ], 
                3], 
            ImageSize -> 800
        ],
        PointLegend[cols, {"one", "two"}, LegendLayout -> "Row", LegendMarkers -> Automatic,
            LegendFunction -> "Frame", LegendLabel -> "Datasets"]
    }, 
    Alignment -> Center]
]
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `LegendMarkers -> Automatic` in `PointLegend ` to match `PlotMarkers -> Automatic` in `ListPlot`.  The OP might want this.

Comment: @Szabolcs Ah yes, thanks. Forgot to add that... Will edit now.

Comment: @rm-rf Nice:clean and simple!

Answer (score 7):

This is not any improvement over rm-rf. In v9 you can also use `Legended`:

```
Module[{f, col = {Red, Blue}, exp, leg, pm = {\[DiamondSuit], 20}},
 f[legend_] := 
  Framed[legend, FrameStyle -> Red, RoundingRadius -> 10, 
   FrameMargins -> 5, Background -> LightBlue];
 exp = GraphicsGrid[
   Partition[
    Table[ListPlot[{Sqrt[Range[0, 50, 5]], 
       Power[Range[0, 50, 5], (3)^-1]}, PlotStyle -> col, 
      PlotMarkers -> pm, Joined -> True], {k, 1, 6}], 3], 
   ImageSize -> 800, Frame -> True];
 leg = LineLegend[col, {"one", "two"}, LegendLayout -> "Row", 
   LegendMarkers -> pm, LegendFunction -> f, 
   LegendLabel -> "Datasets"];
 Legended[Image[exp], Placed[leg, {Center, Below}]]]
```

I made modifications just for illustrative purposes.

[image]