# Make 2D vector norm graph

Tags: vector

I have:

List of points on 2D plane:

```
pointsz0 = ToExpression@Import@"http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VQfP0HgB";
```

And I have some values in those numbers:

```
table = ToExpression@Import@"http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=7g4QNPPw";
```

Now since `pointsz0` are only 2D (notice `z = 0`), I would like to create a 2D graph. At a `point[[1]]` I want `table[[1]]`.

To make things a bit more clear. My numbers are actually vector norms and I would like to make a nice graph showing how the norm of a vector changes in given points. Most likely using colors. That's the idea.

Comment: What do you mean by "_graph_"? Please explain what kind of output you are expecting.

Comment: Well I was hoping to get something similar to DensityPlot: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you can use [`ListDensityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListDensityPlot.html):

```
pointsz0 = ToExpression@Import@"http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VQfP0HgB";
table = ToExpression@Import@"http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=7g4QNPPw";
ListDensityPlot[Append[pointsz0[[#, ;; 2]], table[[#]]] & /@ Range@Length@table]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This will do the job, yes! Thank you!

Comment: You can still look into the `ListDensityPlot` options if you want fancy colours, I don't know what you are into :)

Comment: @skrat You could also use [ListContourPlot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lff3N.png).

Comment: One more question: I have to make three of those, and I prefer ListContourPlot. But the thing is, that I would like to use the same scale (same legend) for all of the three graphs.

Meaning is 1 is white and 0 is blue, I want this to be legend for all the three graphs. How do I do that?

Comment: And, this is of z=0... What would the code be if x=0 or y=0? I can't guess it right..

Comment: @skrat `x = 0` is `data[[#,2;;]]` `y = 0` is `data[[#, {1, 3}]]`. And for the legend stuff, you should look on mma.se e.g. [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41838/1356).

Comment: Huh, Can you let me know where? :D

Comment: =)
One more last thing:
Do you maybe know why the white color in this plot? And why is there no value in the legend? Printscrren: http://www4.slikomat.com/13/0907/xoa-Captur.png

Comment: Ok, that was a lie. This is the last question: Since I already posted the picture in the comment above. You can also see that it doesn't want to label the axes. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @skrat Like I said, look for questions on mma.se for more help. You asked a question and I replied here, and a little more. You haven't shown any effort to actually stick to the mma.se concept via upvoting and accepting, I have no reason to keep helping you. Although you used `AxesLabel` instead of `FrameLabel`, I don't know about the white part, I'm sure your can find out yourself.