# Grid: How to assign a common legend to multiple plots?

Tags: plotting, legending, grid-layouts

I made four plots, named Fig1~Fig4. Then I used Grid to put them together in one figure. Now I wish to add a legend in the bottom of the last figure.

```
Grid[{{Fig1, Fig2}, {Fig3, Fig4}}, Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

Comment: I used ListPlot to create the 4 figures, so they are discrete plots. Besides red and blue colors, I wish the legend to be one circle and one square. This is the hard task for me.

Comment: Have a look [Single Legend for a Table of Plots](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41835/single-legend-for-a-table-of-plots)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Legended` (look at documentation to customize for your needs). Dummy data for illustrative purposes:

```
Legended[Grid[
  Partition[
   Plot[{##}, {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}] & /@ {{1 - x, 
      x^2}, {2 - x, x^2 - 1}, {x, 1 - x^2}, {x + 1, 2 - x^2}}, 2]], 
 LineLegend[{Red, Blue}, {"Condition 1", "Condition 2"}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I used ListPlot to create the 4 figures, so they are discrete plots. Besides red and blue colors, I wish the legend to be one circle and one square. This is the hard task for me.

Comment: @DavidXiaoyuXu I posted this only to provide something you could adapt (as you did  not provide any information). I suggest you look at documentation of legends and search the site for legends and specific markers on this site. Good luck:)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is helpful:

```
myR = Range[10, 80, 10];

lp1 = ListPlot[Sqrt[Range[myR[[1]]]], PlotStyle -> Red, PlotMarkers -> "☐"];

lp2 = ListPlot[Sqrt[Range[myR[[2]]]], PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotMarkers -> "⦿"];

lp3 = ListPlot[Sqrt[Range[myR[[3]]]], PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotMarkers -> "⦿"];

lp4 = ListPlot[Sqrt[Range[myR[[4]]]], PlotStyle -> Red, PlotMarkers -> "☐"];

Legended[Grid[{{lp1, lp2}, {lp3, lp4}}], LineLegend[{Blue, Red}, {"⦿", "☐"}]]
```

[image]